Bounding Norms of Negative Sobolev Spaces
Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open bounded and smooth, $n \geq 2$.
I am reading this paper $L_p$ regularity theorem for elliptic equations in less smooth domains and they define negative Sobolev spaces as $W^{-s,p}(\Omega)$ as the set of functions $f$ such that
\begin{equation}
f=\sum_{|\alpha| \leq s} D^\alpha f_\alpha \quad \text { with } f_\alpha \in L^p.
\end{equation}
with a norm
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{W^{-s,p}(\Omega)}=\inf \left\{\sum_{|\alpha| \leq s}\left\|f_\alpha\right\|_{L^p}: f_{\alpha} \in L^p(\Omega), |\alpha| \leq s \right\}.
\end{equation}
and they claim in inequality (2.2) that
\begin{equation}
\left\|D^\alpha f\right\|_{W^{-s,p}(\Omega)} \leq \|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}, \quad \text { for } f \in L^p(\Omega) \text { and }|\alpha| \leq s.
\end{equation}.
I am wondering however whether the following is also valid?
\begin{equation}
\left\|f\right\|_{W^{-s,p}(\Omega)} \leq \|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}, \quad \text { for } f \in L^p(\Omega).
\end{equation}.
Also since these spaces are defined to be the dual of $W^{s,p}_0$ and we have that
$$W^{s,p}_0 \subset L^2 \subset (W^{s,p}_0)^* \equiv W^{-s,q}$$
where $q$ and $p$ are conjugate.
is it then true that
\begin{equation}
\left\|f\right\|_{W^{-s,p}(\Omega)} \leq \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}, \quad \text { for } f \in L^2(\Omega).
\end{equation}
Any references would be appreciated!
